Extend function type, adding on more param to arg object
So I have a lib that uses a function typed like this:
export declare type SortingStrategy = (args: {
    activeNodeRect: ClientRect | null;
    activeIndex: number;
    index: number;
    rects: ClientRect[];
    overIndex: number;
}) => Transform | null;

I'm passing another prop to this arg object container. So the type will be upgraded to:
type ExtendedSortingStrategy = (args: {
  activeNodeRect: ClientRect | null;
  activeIndex: number;
  index: number;
  rects: ClientRect[];
  overIndex: number;
  container?: HTMLElement | null;
}) => Transform | null;

But I wonder if there's a way to extend the first SortingStrategy, adding the optional property. I didn't find anything that might work in this case so far: func -> args -> object

We can only extend interfaces in TS.  So I think the answer is no, you can at best create an overload as follows, but it's still a new type, i.e. with a new name: type ExtendedSortingStrategy = SortingStrategy & ((args: { ...  }) => Transform  | null);

I'm not sure exactly what you mean by "extend" here, but you can compute ExtendedSortingStrategy in terms of SortingStrategy as shown in this playground link. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

@JulioDiEgidio If I do so, vscode shows every prop parameter as wrong in the IDE.
type ExtendedSortingStrategy = SortingStrategy & ((args: { container: HTMLElement | null }) => Transform  | null);
export const customStrategy: ExtendedSortingStrategy = ({
  rects,
  activeNodeRect: fallbackActiveRect,
  activeIndex,
  overIndex,
  index,
  container
}) => {


@jcalz What you propose works well. Thank you. But I would like you to describe how you got to this solution, pointing to documentation. So I understand how it works.

@jordãoFrançaBarroso  I don't know what you mean, see this playground  AIUI, @jcalz is doing the same just to the args: maybe that's better...?

Yes, I like @jcalz 's solution, less code duplication for pretty much the same effect.

There's no automatic way to do this.  Given your SortingStrategy type you could use a conditional type to extract the parameter and return types, modify the parameter type and make a new function type, like this:
type ExtendedSortingStrategy = SortingStrategy extends (args: infer A) => infer R ?
  (args: A & { container?: HTMLElement | null }) => R : never

That evaluates to
type ExtendedSortingStrategy = (args: {
  activeNodeRect: ClientRect | null;
  activeIndex: number;
  index: number;
  rects: ClientRect[];
  overIndex: number;
} & {
  container?: HTMLElement | null | undefined;
}) => Transform | null

which is equivalent to what you wanted (it uses an intersection instead of a single object type. You could go through more trouble and collapse the intersection to a single object type if it matters, but I'll consider that out of scope here).
The conditional type above is more straightforward than using the Parameters and the ReturnType utility types, but it's the same idea.

And it suffers from the same drawbacks; if SortingStrategy were generic or overloaded it wouldn't work well. Ideally one should start with the argument type and build both SortingStrategy and ExtendedSortingStrategy from it, to avoid having to try to "unwrap and rewrap" a function type.  Obviously that's not always possible for every use case, but it's simpler and less fragile.
Playground link to code
